# How to save user info from LinkedIn API into Angularjs controller using a custom service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, linkedin-api

Im new to angular and I'm having trouble saving user info from LinkedIn API to the scope in my controller without passing the scope to my custom service. I assume that is not the angular way of programming.

```
//html

<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
  api_key: *********
  onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
</script>

// linkedIn button

<script type="in/Login">
</script>

// app.js

angular.module("linkedinTestApp",[]);

function onLinkedInLoad(){
  eScope.$apply(function(){
    eScope.getLinkedInData();
  })
};

// main controller

var eScope;
angular.module("linkedinTestApp").
controller('mainCtrl',function($scope,linkedInService){
  eScope = $scope;

  $scope.getLinkedInData = function(){
    linkedInService.OnLinkedInFrameworkLoad($scope);
  }
})

//custom service

angular.module('linkedinTestApp')
.service('linkedInService', function() {
    var scope;
    this.OnLinkedInFrameworkLoad = function(s) {
      scope = s;
      IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", this.OnLinkedInAuth);
      console.log("Test1");
    }

    this.OnLinkedInAuth = function() {
      IN.API.Profile("me").result(function(result){
        console.log(result);
        var profile = {
            vnaam: result.values[0].firstName,
            anaam: result.values[0].lastName,
            foto: result.values[0].pictureUrl,
            headline: result.values[0].headline,
            id: result.values[0].id
        }
        console.log(profile);
        scope.profile = profile;
      });
      console.log("Test2");
    }
});
```

Comment: I want to safe the profile object in my scope in the controller without passing the scope to the service.

Comment: @AlonEitan forgot to include ur name

Comment: Since this is an async process, you need to pass a promise and resolve it when you have the details from linkedin. Read more about [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), this [tutorial](http://markdalgleish.com/2013/06/using-promises-in-angularjs-views/) might also help you understand how it works

Comment: Correction - you should PASS a promise to the service, the service should return the promise from the function. Sorry about that

Comment: @AlonEitan I have already tried to attach a promise in my controller after i call the function from my service but i always get undefined as a return because the function is executed when the webpage is loaded and the profile object only gets filled when the user is loged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested code. Took me 20-30 minutes to get api key and when i tested someone posted answer, but my code was tested so a post this, similar, answer. Also this is not the most elegant way to get profile in the controller, but I wanted to change as little code as possible(for similary).

```
angular.module("linkedinTestApp",[]);

function onLinkedInLoad(){
  eScope.$apply(function(){
    eScope.getLinkedInData();
  })
};

// main controller

var eScope;
angular.module("linkedinTestApp").
controller('mainCtrl',function($scope,linkedInService){
  eScope = $scope;

  $scope.getLinkedInData = function(){
    linkedInService.OnLinkedInFrameworkLoad().then(function(profile){
      console.log('response ', profile);
  });
  }
})

//custom service

angular.module('linkedinTestApp')
.service('linkedInService', function($q) {
    this.OnLinkedInFrameworkLoad = function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", function(){
        deferred.resolve(OnLinkedInAuth())
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    }

    function OnLinkedInAuth() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      IN.API.Profile("me").result(function(result){
        console.log(result);
        var profile = {
            vnaam: result.values[0].firstName,
            anaam: result.values[0].lastName,
            foto: result.values[0].pictureUrl,
            headline: result.values[0].headline,
            id: result.values[0].id
        }
        deferred.resolve(profile);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway +1

Comment: I will use your way of doing it. I prefer less code so thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```
angular.module('linkedinTestApp').service('linkedInService', function($q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var self = this;
    this.profile = null;

    this.OnLinkedInFrameworkLoad = function() {
      IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", this.OnLinkedInAuth);
      console.log("Test1");
    } // NOT SURE IF THIS FUNCTION IS NEEDED, OR WHO CALLS IT, MAYBE YOU NEED TO JUST REPLACE IT WITH THE NEXT LINE:
    // IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", this.OnLinkedInAuth);

    this.OnLinkedInAuth = function() {
      IN.API.Profile("me").result(function(result){
        console.log(result);
        deferred.resolve( {
            vnaam: result.values[0].firstName,
            anaam: result.values[0].lastName,
            foto: result.values[0].pictureUrl,
            headline: result.values[0].headline,
            id: result.values[0].id
        } );
      });
      console.log("Test2");
    }

    this.instance = function() {
         return deferred.promise;
    }
});
```

And use it in your controller:

```
$scope.linkedInService.instance().then(
   function(profile) {
       console.log(profile);
   }
);
```

Of course I haven't tested it, but I hope it will work...

Comment: The thing is now i cant call my getLinkedInData function because the api uses a onload and i cant call functions from my controller in that onload. I used some code to call it(as seen above) but now it's not working.

Comment: I fixed it by calling the instance() function on the service itself instead of on the function of the controller.

Comment: My bad, it should be `$scope.linkedInService.instance()`

Comment: Thanks for the response i got it working with your help i only made some small adjustments to the code for the controller.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// main controller

    angular.module("linkedinTestApp").
    controller('mainCtrl',function($scope,linkedInService){

      $scope.getLinkedInData = function(){
        linkedInService.OnLinkedInFrameworkLoad().then (function (result) {
             $scope.profile = result;
        });
      }
    })

    //custom service

    angular.module('linkedinTestApp')
    .service('linkedInService', function() {
        this.OnLinkedInFrameworkLoad = function() {
          return this.OnLinkedInAuth();
        }

        this.OnLinkedInAuth = function() {
          return IN.API.Profile("me").result(function(result){
            console.log(result);
            var profile = {
                vnaam: result.values[0].firstName,
                anaam: result.values[0].lastName,
                foto: result.values[0].pictureUrl,
                headline: result.values[0].headline,
                id: result.values[0].id
            }
            console.log(profile);
            return profile;
          });
        }
    });
```